# How to load Image into ImageView from Url using Glide v4.0.0RC1

Tags: android, android-glide

I just updated Glide library from v3 to v4 in my application. 
But Now I am not able to load image from the url. Previously it was working fine with v3.

Here is my Glide code:

```
Glide.with(context).load(galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage()).thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.balls)).apply(options).into(holder.kolamImage);
```

What is the change in v4? I went through the document but still no help.

Comment: try logging `galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage()`, you can add a `.listener()` too before `.into()`

Comment: Image url is coming perfectly. But the image is not getting download by Glide. I am calling the above line inside `onBindViewHolder()` of an `Adapter`. Earlier it was working with v3

Comment: maybe something to do with broken cache

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using **Glide v4.0.0-RC1** then you need to use `RequestOptions` to add the placeholder, error image and other option. Here is an working example

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);



 Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Comment: does glide also cache image that is loaded from internet?

Comment: can we add rounded corners for imageview using glide?

Answer (score 8):

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("url here") // image url
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // any placeholder to load at start
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)  // any image in case of error
        .override(200, 200) // resizing
        .centerCrop()     
        .into(imageView);  // imageview object
```

Answer (score 4):

**Below Steps is for load image into imageView from URL :-**

> create a new Activity like this and load image from given url.

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myOfferImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView myOfferImageView;
    String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        url = "https://image.url"


        myOfferImageView = findViewById(R.id.myOfferImage);
        Glide.with(this).load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(myOfferImageView);
    }


}
```

Comment: can i use this in gridview ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490176/how-to-display-firebase-storage-images-in-gridview

Comment: @Kingg Yes you can.

Answer (score 3):

Glide v4 added a feature of `RequestOptions` to add placeholder ,error image and to customize image.

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.your_placeholder_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.your_error_image);

Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have quotes around your url, with ivProfileImage being your imageview.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .asBitmap()
    .load("https://i2.wp.com/www.siasat.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Rosamund-Pike.jpeg?fit=600%2C421&ssl=1")
    .into(ivProfileImage);
```

Comment: can i use this in gridview ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490176/how-to-display-firebase-storage-images-in-gridview