# Glide is blank when loading Firestore reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-glide

I am using Glide 4.9.0 with firestore in Android Kotlin.

Images are getting save in firestore with path. But when i try to load path reference to Glide, it shows nothing but set imageview blank .

Activity Code:

```
FirestoreUtil.getCurrentStudent { student ->    

                    Glide.with(this)
                        .load(student?.profilePicturePath.toString())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                        .transform(CircleCrop())
                        .into(stdProfile)
                }
```

Firestore Path:

```
gs://xxxx-xxxxx.appspot.com/xybyiF9LkxXorrrEgu3PKpy6b6t1/profilePictures/94af9ef2-12f6-3657-8367-2e505bc37cc2
```

url from firestore database and storage:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the log of path and Firebase storage Location

Comment: @Ashish i have updated question with Firestore Path

Comment: ali the path your provided is not perfect. Cause there is no Extension to your file. Please check your path. It needs to be something like this `gs://**.appspot.com/images/6g74sRdiPh5BVApVtOFM.jpg`

Comment: Thank you @Ashish, So issue is in uploading image. 
My code for uploading image is

Comment: fun uploadProfilePhoto(imageBytes: ByteArray, onSuccess: (imagePath: String) -> Unit){

        val ref = currentStudentRef.child("profilePictures/${UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(imageBytes)}")
        ref.putBytes(imageBytes).addOnSuccessListener {
            onSuccess(ref.path)
        }
    }

Comment: can you guide that how i can make extension from this function?

Comment: Please shouw us how is your url stored in the database as a screenshot please. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @ALi Issue isn't with uploading image i think issue is in your Database storing.

Comment: @AlexMamo updated question with screenshots

Comment: @ALi you didn't convert imagebyte. Please check the [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=1#upload_from_data_in_memory). You need to follow those steps and convert into byteArray

Comment: That's not a proper url. Check the way you are uploading that url.

Comment: @AlexMamo now my url is gs://xxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/xybyiF9LkxXorrrEgu3PKpy6b6t1/profilePictures/me.jpg

but still its blank

Comment: @ALi Can you open that url in browser?

Comment: it opens in browser when i add "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/" in start

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue was not the URL, my url is correct.

This [post](https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/displaying-images-from-firebase-storage-using-glide-for-kotlin-projects-3e4950f6c103) helped me to show gs url in Glide using Firestore UI.

Thanks

Comment: Did you store the actual images in Storage and store the url in Firestore and then show them with FirestoreUI?

Answer (score 0):

Additional to ALis Link I had to add Request options to the GlideApp for it to work with the following versions:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.1.0'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Taken from: [How to load Image into ImageView from Url using Glide v4.0.0RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232608/how-to-load-image-into-imageview-from-url-using-glide-v4-0-0rc1)

```
val options : RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
    .centerInside()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
    .load(imageRef)
    .apply(options)
    .into(imageView)
```