# I Want to load image from json in my assest as a string and then pass it to an imageview. How to do it?

Tags: java, android, json, imageview

I Want to load image from json in my assest as a string  and then pass it  to an imageview. How to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485420/how-do-you-put-an-image-file-in-a-json-object answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Say your json is something like:

```
const book = {
id: 1,
title: "my title",
img:"/image/file.png",
...
}
...
```

you may pass that object directly in your image tag:

eg.

```
<img src="{book.img}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Library like Glide and Picasso for load image in imageview as a string
Please check below link
[How to load Image into ImageView from Url using Glide v4.0.0RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232608/how-to-load-image-into-imageview-from-url-using-glide-v4-0-0rc1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the whole image in your JSON, than you could use base64 to convert from byte[] to String and vice versa. Java has base64 encoders and decoders in it's util packages. Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.